# Serve multiple type files on pure node.js

Tags: node.js, server, static, response, request-headers

I have a simple pure node.js server which sends back html page on request.
In my html page i have connected js file.
When i make a request i get on response the html page but no the js file.
In my console i got an error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

my node.js server file:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html', });
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data){
        if(err){
          return console.log(err);
        }
      res.end(data);
    });
}).listen(8080);
console.log('Server is running on Port: 8080');
```

my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>here</h1>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions how to send multiple files on request with pure js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently serving all requests with `index.html`, so when the browser requests `app.js` you do not get the script, but the index-page instead, hence the error.

You'd need to check the request path in your server's callback and then send the correct file (see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Node_server_without_framework) for a more detailed example):

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.path === '/app.js') {
       // read app.js file and send it to the client
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html', });
      fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data){
        if(err){
          return console.log(err);
        }
       res.end(data);
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

You see that this is pretty cumbersome, so I highly recommend using a framework like [express](https://expressjs.com/) (it provides a middleware to serve static files out of the box) to do this.

Comment: I don't wanna send app.js file, i wanna send html file with app.js file.

Comment: That's not how it works  ... your browser requests and gets `index.html` where `app.js` is referenced. Your browser will then send a request for `app.js`. You cannot send both files it in one response. Of course you could include the scripts contents into the html directly (`<script>content of app.js here</script>`) , but if you reference it, a separate request is made for it.

Comment: How can i handle this (sending app.js file on request after sending html)

Comment: That's what I tried to show you in  my code example.. please read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Node_server_without_framework -> it explains it really well.